# Tap publisher execute twice in Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I'd like not to use `saveButton.addTarget(:selector:event)` that's why
I try to use tap publisher from ***[CombineCocoa](https://github.com/CombineCommunity/CombineCocoa)*** framework like this

```
 saveButton.tapPublisher.sink {  _ in
        print("tap") // tap twice
    }
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

and when I tap `saveButton` then 'tap' printed twice.

Also I try to use from ***Combine*** framework

```
saveButton.publisher(for: .touchUpInside)
```

but have the same result.

My code here

```
class ArticleVC: UIViewController {
    let saveButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)
        return btn
    }()
    
    var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // add to view
        view.addSubview(saveButton)
        didTapSave()
        saveButton.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.centerX.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        didTapSave()
    }
    
    func didTapSave() {
//        saveButton.tapPublisher.sink(receiveValue: { _ in
//            print("tap")  // twice printed 'tap'
//        })
//        .store(in: &subscriptions)
        /// OR
        saveButton.publisher(for: .touchUpInside).sink { _ in
            print("tap") // twice printed 'tap'
        }
        .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}
```

What the reason for it?

Comment: This is waaaaaaaay too little context for anyone to help in any meaningful way.

Comment: I would add: who lives _by_ the third-party framework must live _with_ the third-party framework. I like the idea of a button that publishes, but I prefer to implement that myself so I know what I'm getting and am not reliant on someone else's code.

Comment: @Alexander thanks, is it enough?

Comment: @matt thanks, I also use Combine - it's Apple's framework

Comment: Not really. I could google `CombineCocoa`, but that doesn't give me any of the context that's probably relevant to the situation. What's `saveButton`, I assume just a `UIButton`, but I don't know that. What's the type of the parameter that you discarded with `_`? Perhaps it's an `UIEvent` that tells you whether the event is a push down or a release. I also don't know where you're putting this initialization code, perhaps you're accidentally making two subscriptions, and each fires once. I'm not a mind reader, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Alexander I found my problem: func ```didTapSave()``` call twice in ```viewDidLoad()```. I didn't saw it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Combine is Apple's framework but CombineCocoa is not, so if it has a problem, you inherit it. However the matter is now settled as your typo.

Comment: @Taras We could found that instantly if you had just provided your code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are creating the pipeline twice. But you have not shown where you create the pipeline, so that is just a guess. [**EDIT**: Well after I posted this answer, you posted your code in the question, and my guess turned out to be obviously correct, as we can now *see* you creating the pipeline twice.]

To support this, I'll show what I did:

- I created a new iOS project.
- I put a button in the interface and hooked an outlet from my ViewController.
- I installed the package https://github.com/CombineCommunity/CombineCocoa.git
- I configured my ViewController code:

```
import UIKit
import Combine
import CombineCocoa

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.tapPublisher
            .sink { _ in print("tap") }
            .store(in: &storage)
    }
}
```

That is all the code there is. I run the project, I tap the button, I see "tap" once. The end.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot. My fault was that ```func didTapSave()``` calls twice in ```viewDidLoad()```

Comment: Yep, now that you've shown the code, that's obvious.